# Email already sent?

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone explain a simple solution using MySQL and PHP how to check if an email has been sent already, stopping duplicates for users.

I have a basic script, but it's not working for some reason - http://pastebin.com/k7yiQahb
It inserts into the table the following:

`feed_id,   recipient_id,   issent` 
    `0,     0,  Y`

Regards

Comment: I suggest reading a book instead of trying to make a script work.

Comment: I asked about something like this on one level higher, here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847732/best-practice-to-avoid-add-friend-abuse

Comment: @kitsched thanks for sharing the link :-) Did you end up implementing it? I had this idea first up, but it seemed pretty hard to implement, hence went with a tracking table like this (as suggested by fellow SO members). Although I'm stuck with MySQL and variables. The end result will be it sending an email to an SMS gateway, which SMS's the user's #.

Comment: If you are only concerned with the user not pressing the 'Send' button in a form more than once, you could use Javascript to disable the button after one push. Just in case this apply and you haven't thought about it already. =)

Answer (score 0):

**Why not create a column `issent` of type `enum(Yes,No) DEFAULT 'No'` in the table `recipients` instead of a separate table.**

Then, when email is sent successfully, run this:

```
 update `recipients` set issent = 'Yes' where id = $id
```

And when you are fetching email recipients in the beginning, just do:

```
 select email, suburb, id FROM recipients where issent = 'No' GROUP BY id ORDER BY id DESC
```

This will give you only unsent addresses.

**[EDIT]: If there are multiple recipients, you can run first query like this:**

```
 update `recipients` set issent = 'Yes' where id IN (3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: However, the messages are one-to-many, so each message MAY be sent to several recipients. Which means this way is flawed, right?

Comment: Well, it seems to run error free. However emails arent being sent. When run manually, its #1054 - Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Just realised this wont work because each recipient will be getting multiple emails from time to time based on feed.id.

Comment: Uhh, you have to replace $id with whatever variable you're having. Use this: `mysql_query("update recipients set issent = 'Yes' where id = '{$recipient_id}' ");`